# How do I remove a column/variable titled NA in R dataframe?

Tags: r

I used bind_rows() and the result has a variable NA at the end that is making subsequent use of the dataframe impossible.  I tried to remove it by I keep getting this error.

Error: Column `125` cannot have NA as name

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the output from `dput(head(<your dataframe))` so that we can see xactly what has happened here.  But `df <- df %>% select(-125)` might do the trick.  You can refer to columns by index in `dplyr` verbs.  Oh - and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that one of the column names is NA, you could rename the problematic column if you want to keep it:

`colnames(df)[125] <- "NAME"`

Or if you want to remove it:

`df[-125]`